# Задача о кирпичной кладке

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Имеется слой кирпичной кладки размером N на M клеток. Один кирпич занимает ровно две смежных клетки. Требуется рассчитать один из вариантов размещения кирпичей в следующем слое кладки.

Ограничение: ни один из кирпичей нового слоя не должен полностью совпадать положением ни с одним кирпичом предыдущего слоя.

Входные данные - матрица NxM, представляющая слой кладки, заполненная парами чисел от 1 до NxM/2, где каждая пара чисел представляет собой один кирпич.

Пример входных данных и пример ответа:

[image: screenshot]

т.е. на входе матрица:

```
{
    {  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4 },
    {  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8 },
    {  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12 },
    { 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16 },
}
```

на выходе:

```
{
    {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8 },
    {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8 },
    {  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 },
    {  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 },
}
```

Тестовый метод для проверки корректности слоя:

```
public bool CheckLayers(int n, int m, int[,] current, int[,] previous)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            if (i < n - 1
                && current[i, j] == current[i + 1, j]
                && previous[i, j] == previous[i + 1, j]) return false;
            if (j < m - 1
                && current[i, j] == current[i, j + 1]
                && previous[i, j] == previous[i, j + 1]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74100/discussion-on-question-by--nop----).

Comment: Ээ, а почему «соревнование»? Где критерии оценки ответов?

Comment: А хз, метка не моя, я лишь объяву разместил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, рассмотрим всевозможные участки 2х2 клетки слоя кладки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, для любого участка 2х2 клетки всегда есть возможность подобрать пару кирпичей для установки в следующем слое: т.е. если в участке один из кирпичей расположен "горизонтально" (на самом деле весь слой горизонтальный, но для удобства обозначения я его поместил вертикально), то берем пару "вертикальных" кирпичей, иначе берем пару "горизонтальных". На картинках красными прямоугольниками я обозначил *возможное* размещение кирпичей в следующем слое. Обратите внимание, если на выбранном участке 2х2 все клетки заняты "половинками", т.е. нет ни одного целого кирпича, то пару кирпичей в следующем слое можно разместить как вертикально, так и горизонтально, т.е. вышеописанный алгоритм работает и для этого случая.

Таким образом, если *оба входных значения N и M четные*, то слой кладки можно разбить на участки 2х2 клетки и заполнить их по вышеописанному алгоритму. Для четных N и M решение всегда существует и тривиально.

Теперь, рассмотрим случай, когда N или M нечетно. Следует заметить, что если одновременно и N, и M являются нечетными, то мы не можем замостить слой целым количеством кирпичей, т.е. таких входных данных быть не может и этот случай мы не рассматриваем.

Итак, один из размеров слоя кладки нечетный. Рассмотрим случай, когда нечетной является "ширина" M, если нечетна "высота" N, то мы всегда можем транспонировать входные данные и воспользоваться этим же алгоритмом.

"Разобьем" кладку на "горизонтальные" полосы высотой 2 клетки (высота четная, поэтому это возможно) и рассмотрим каждую полосу независимо от других. Для такой полосы мы обязаны разместить хотя бы один из кирпичей вертикально, причем этот кирпич должен стоять в 0, 2, 4, ..., (M-3) или (M-1) вертикали (если у нас вертикальный кирпич расположен в вертикали с нечетным индексом, то будет еще как минимум один (два даже) вертикальный кирпич в вертикали с четным индексом и мы будем рассматривать именно его). Что примечательно - слева и справа от вертикального кирпича окажется четное число вертикалей.

Т.е. для каждой горизонтальной полосы высотой 2 клетки мы просматриваем вертикали с четными индексами и если на какой-то из этих вертикалей не расположен вертикальный кирпич, то мы помещаем вертикальный кирпич в следующем слое, а участки слева и справа от него заполняем по алгоритму для четных N и M. Если же в полосе 2xM все четные вертикали заняты вертикальными кирпичами, то решения нет.

Доказать корректность алгоритма я не могу, но подобрать опровергающий пример входных данных мне не удалось.

Остается только перевести этот алгоритм в код.

Наивная реализация на C#:

```
class Layer
{
    int[,] array;
    int n, m;
    public bool IsTransposed { get; set; } = false;
    public int N => IsTransposed ? m : n;
    public int M => IsTransposed ? n : m;

    public Layer(int[,] bricks) => (n, m, array) = (bricks.GetLength(0), bricks.GetLength(1), bricks);
    public Layer(int n, int m) : this(new int[n, m]) { }

    public int this[int row, int column]
    {
        get => IsTransposed ? array[column, row] : array[row, column];
        set => array[IsTransposed ? column : row, IsTransposed ? row : column] = value;
    }

    public Layer GenerateNext()
    {
        if (N % 2 + M % 2 == 2) return null;
        var next = new Layer(N, M);
        var index = 0;
        if (N % 2 + M % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < N; row += 2)
                for (int column = 0; column < M; column += 2)
                    Fill(row, column);
        }
        else
        {
            if (N % 2 == 1) IsTransposed = next.IsTransposed = true;
            for (int row = 0; row < N; row += 2)
            {
                bool exist = false;
                int reservedColumn = 0;
                for (int column = 0; column < M; column += 2)
                    if (this[row, column] != this[row + 1, column])
                    {
                        exist = true;
                        reservedColumn = column;
                        break;
                    }
                if (!exist) return null;
                next[row, reservedColumn] = next[row + 1, reservedColumn] = ++index;
                for (int column = 0; column < reservedColumn; column += 2)
                    Fill(row, column);
                for (int column = reservedColumn + 1; column < M; column += 2)
                    Fill(row, column);
            }
            IsTransposed = next.IsTransposed = false;
        }
        return next;

        void Fill(int r, int c)
        {
            if (this[r, c] == this[r, c + 1] ||
                this[r + 1, c] == this[r + 1, c + 1])
            {
                next[r, c] = next[r + 1, c] = ++index;
                next[r, c + 1] = next[r + 1, c + 1] = ++index;
            }
            else
            {
                next[r, c] = next[r, c + 1] = ++index;
                next[r + 1, c] = next[r + 1, c + 1] = ++index;
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        int max = this[0, 0];
        for (int row = 0; row < N; ++row)
            for (int column = 0; column < M; ++column)
                if (this[row, column] > max) max = this[row, column];
        int d = max.ToString().Length;
        var format = "{0," + d + "} ";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int row = 0; row < N; ++row)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < M; ++column)
                sb.AppendFormat(format, this[row, column]);
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
int[,] bricks =
{
    {  1,  1,  2,  2,  7,  3,  4,  4 },
    {  5,  9,  6,  6,  7,  3,  8, 12 },
    {  5,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11,  8, 12 },
    { 13, 13, 14, 18, 15, 15, 16, 16 }
};
var layer = new Layer(bricks);
var nextLayer = layer.GenerateNext();
Console.WriteLine(layer);
if (nextLayer != null) Console.WriteLine(nextLayer);
else Console.WriteLine("Нет решения!");
```

Comment: это подразумевает, что только целый кирпич разрешён (смежные клетки по диагонали не могут быть) и нельзя добавлять кирпичей.

Comment: Да, кирпичи только целые. Добавлять? Кирпичей ровно NxM/2, не больше и не меньше.

Comment: На входе NxM/2 кирпичей, сколько на выходе кирпичей ничего не сказано. В ответах на вопросы с меткой [соревнование] разрешено всё, что явно не запрещено. К примеру, ответ на `{{1,1}}` случай: `{{1,2}}` (два кирпича, занимающих 2-ой и 3-ий слой -- вертикально поставлены) или `{{1,NaN}}` (один вертикально поставленный кирпич) или `{{1,NaN}, {1,NaN}}` (повернут кирпич на 90 градусов)

Answer (score 0):

Можно короче

- если одна размеренность чётная укладываем кирпичи вдоль по ней, если две можно вдоль двух
- если очень надо уложить вдоль нечётной, укладываем вдоль неё все кроме последнего кирпича, последний поперёк, следующий ряд так же (будет использоваться тот кирпич что поперёк)
- если очень надо уложить когда N и M нечётные, выбрав направление укладываем вдоль первого ряда без последнего кирпича и дальше ряды как в предыдущем пункте, теряем одну клетку.

Comment: Вы ничего не написали про исходный ряд, его мы вообще не будем смотреть? Скорее всего кирпичи в нем будут расположены не так удобно...